Is "wrought havoc" the past tense of "work havoc"?
In the book entitled The Webs of Humankind, it says:

Introduced crowd diseases wrought havoc for five or six generations (of indigenous peoples).

https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/do-you-wreak-havoc-or-wreck-it says

Incidentally, the past tense of the phrase is wreaked havoc, as one
might expect, but for much of the 20th century, many people preferred
wrought havoc, even though wrought is actually a past tense not of
wreak but of work. Happily, English speakers seem largely to have
outgrown that habit.

Is "wrought" in "wrought havoc" actually the past tense form of "work"? So besides "wreak havoc" and "wreck havoc", there is also "work havoc"? Is "work havoc" recommended as much as "wreak havoc"?

Discussion here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/304867/the-wrought-wreaked-havoc-misunderstanding

"Work havoc" is no more recommended than "I wrought in an office".

"Wrought" is a component of a few fixed phrases such as "wrought iron".  It does derive from the past participle of the middle English werken  (which became modern English "work")
However the past participle and past tense of "work" are now "worked".
"Wreak" is another word that is now only found as a "fossil" in the phrase  "wreak havoc" (and related phrases like "wreak vengeance").  In Middle English it was wreken and it had two possible inflections, either "wreken-wrook-gewroken" or "wreken-wreekte-gewroken".  In modern English this would be "wreak-wreaked-wrok"
It is all a bit unnecessary
Some people feel that "wrought havoc" is wrong.  So if you care about these people, then don't use it.  Similarly many think "wreck havoc" is wrong.  There is some use of both of these.
There is no use of "work havoc", so don't use that. Also, don't use "wrought" as the past tense of "work" in modern English.

I do use the wreak but only in conjunction with the word havoc.  So things in my world can wreak havoc but that is the limit of what can be wreaked.

In my world we also are known to wreak vengeance. But the last time I heard that phrase was probably from the mouth of a Premier League football match color commentator.

I don't think so. "Wrought" is the past tense of "wreak". "Wreak" and "havoc" are two fairly inseparable words. Off the top of my head, I can't think of a sentence that uses one without the other. (But see comment below).

We can wreak vengeance, mayhem, a disaster. devastation, and things can to lead to, or cause, havoc. These are not exhaustive lists.

Haha - I'm clearly too Canadian!
